# Issue with Spring security's logout

Tags: spring-security

I've got a problem logging out in Spring framework.

First when I want j_spring_security_logout to handle it for me i get 404 j_spring_security_logout not found:
sample-security.xml:

```xml
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/messageList.htm*" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_GUEST" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/messagePost.htm*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/messageDelete.htm*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <form-login login-page="/login.jsp" default-target-url="/messageList.htm"
        authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?error=true" />
    <logout/>
</http>
```

Sample url link to logout in JSP page:

```jsp
<a href="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout" />">Logout</a>
```

When i try to use a custom JSP page i.e. I use login form for this purpose then I get better result at least it gets to login page, but another problem is that you dont't get logged off as you can diretcly type url that should be guarded buy you get past it anyway.

Slightly modified from previous listings:

```xml
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/messageList.htm*" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_GUEST" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/messagePost.htm*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/messageDelete.htm*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <form-login login-page="/login.jsp" default-target-url="/messageList.htm"
        authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?error=true" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login.jsp" />
</http>
```

```jsp
<a href="<c:url value="/login.jsp" />">Logout</a>
```

Thank you for help

Comment: hi, I have done as javascript and passed csrf token too but I am not able to login again once logged out.. after logout my login page is showing with some csrf token which is different then when I reload login page, and not able to login again, it says `http://192.168.6.51:8044/EWTS/auth/login_check;jsessionid=403A583CDDC688292408C7C76CD09F2D?targetUrl=` not found

Comment: After logout, how to remove csrf token???

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've just had this problem.

You need to make sure in `web.xml` your security filter matches on the url /j_spring_security_logout

e.g.

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class> 
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/j_spring_security_logout</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 7):

You should do POST request. Something like that:

```xml
<form action="${logoutUrl}" method="post" id="logoutForm">
            <input type="hidden" 
                    name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                    value="${_csrf.token}" />
</form>

<script>
    function formSubmit() {
                document.getElementById("logoutForm").submit();
    }
</script>

<c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
           <h2>
                Welcome : ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name} | 
                 <a href="javascript:formSubmit()"> Logout</a>
            </h2>
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem and after loosing hope, finally I found out the answer by accident.
Of course we learn a lot by reading and using someone else's codes and, by doing this we inherit settings we don't know much about.

And this is what happened to me when programming using Spring Security.

In the Spring Security XML, within the **http** tag, there is this line:

```xml
<logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/login" logout-url="/logout" />
```

I got this line during my research from some tutorial or example. And after 2 days struggling with the **j_spring_security_logout** keyword and getting nothing but error 404, I figured out this.

In the **logout** tag I am using, there's this *logout-url* parameter set to "/logout". Then I realized that according to my settings, my spring is expecting to receive **/logout** instead of **/j_spring_security_logout**.

Once I updated my code accordingly, it worked like a charm.

Comment: How does Spring know which user to logout? Shouldn't one be sending the username or something?

Comment: There's no way to be logged in a system with two different users. When you log in, Spring keeps your user in the browser's session and this is the one that's logged out.

Comment: Worked like a charm.
I was doing the same mistake i did not added the logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"

Answer (score 2):

Is logout link aware of the context path?

For example, if your context path is "myapp", where does the above mentioned link point?

"http://localhost:8080/myapp/j_spring_security_logout" or "http://localhost:8080/j_spring_security_logout" ?

In fact, the j_spring_security_logout is only valid within the context of the webapp so only the first link would lead to the correct url

Answer (score 1):

Try this link in your page whow content a logout link:

```xml
<h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/logout.jsp">Logout</h:outputLink>
```

and creeate a logout.jsp file in your "webcontent" folder with the following code:

```xml
<% response.sendRedirect("/#{request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_logout"); %>
```

if an eror occured try to change "#{request.contextPath}" to the name of your project
ex: my project name is "security" so i am using in my logout.jsp file:

```xml
<% response.sendRedirect("/security/j_spring_security_logout"); %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

**Seems to be a bug on 3.0.6!**

> I just downgrade to 3.0.5 and everything works nicely.