# In Spring-Security what exactly is the j_spring_security_logout? Ive heard it referred to as "handler" but I'm not sure what that means

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've been learning spring and spring-security and came across auto-config="true" attribute for the  tag in the spring security context. I was introduced to j_spring_security_logout as the url to submit to for logging out functionality in jsp.

Used like this in the jsp:

```
<a href="../j_spring_security_logout">logout buddy</a></p>
<a href="../j_spring_security_login">login</a></p>
```

What exactly is this j_spring_security_logout (magic) provided by Spring?
I've heard it being referred to as a handler. But I have no idea what that means.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050840/call-to-j-spring-security-logout-not-working

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When a request to `/j_spring_security_logout` is sent by a browser initially it goes to `org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutFilter` which then delegates the logout task to a `org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutHandler` implementation

`org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/SecurityContextLogoutHandler` is an implementation of `LogoutHandler` and it has a method `logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)` which will be called by `LogoutFilter`.

The `LogoutHandler` primarily does two things;

1. Invalidates the session if it is configured to do so
2. Clears the `SecurityContextHolder` which is where Authentication details are stored.

Comment: So what is the LogoutFilter? Is it related to the servlet filter concept? What is the relationship between the logout filter and the logouthandler? thank you!

Comment: Yes LogoutFilter implements Filter which is Servlet Filter. The relationship of LogoutFilter and LogoutHanlder is one to many where a LogoutFilter can have multiple LogoutHandlers.