# spring authentication: can't logout

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm new to Spring. I can't logout with spring security.
Login works fine, and  I'm following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050840/call-to-j-spring-security-logout-not-working) to implement the logout function.

but I can't make it work.
here's my spring-security.xml:

```
<security:http auto-config="true"  use-expressions="true">
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/index" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
  <security:logout logout-success-url="/index" logout-url="/logout" />   
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
  <security:authentication-provider>
    <security:user-service>
      <security:user name="matt3o" password="secret" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
    </security:user-service>
  </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

and here's my index.jsp:

```
<c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
  <h2>Welcome : ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}         
</c:if>
<p><a href="logout">Logout</a></p>
```

Please can somebody explain to me how loggin/loggout works and why my logout doesn't ?

In index.jsp I'm trying to logout in different ways, none of them works:

```
<!--1-->
<c:url value="/logout" var="logoutUrl" />
<form id="logout" action="${logoutUrl}" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
</form>
<c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logout').submit()">Logout</a>
</c:if>
<br><br>

<!--2-->
<a href="logout">logout1</a>             
<br><br>

<!--3-->
<a href='<c:url value="j_spring_security_logout" />'>logout</a>
```

Comment: There is nothing in there for login, so you have at least not included the full configuration. Next to that your link is wrong `logout` is relative, while you probably want a absolute URL to `/logout`.

Comment: gotta POST to logout now

Comment: @M.Deinum I've added the authentication manager to my post. that's all I have in the security configuration file. the login works fine.

Comment: Which version of Spring Security do you use?

Comment: Then you need to post to login not a get. So the link is doing nothing you need a form and submit that to the logout URL, and remember to include the csfr token.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security 4 requires a POST request to logout instead of a GET. Next to that by default it is secured using a CSFR token, which you would need to add to the form (see the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/LogoutConfigurer.html#logoutUrl(java.lang.String))).

So instead of a link use a form to invoke the logout.

```
<c:url var="logoutUrl" value="/logout"/>
<form action="${logoutUrl}" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Log out" />
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
</form>
```

or when using the security tag library

```
<c:url var="logoutUrl" value="/logout"/>
<form action="${logoutUrl}" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Log out" />
    <sec:csrfInput />
</form>
```

See also [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token-form) and [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-logout) in the reference guide.

If you want to use a GET either configure the logout functionality as such that it supports GET requests (for this you need to provide an ant matcher) or by disabling CSFR which can be done by adding `<sec:csfr disabled="true" />` to your xml configuration.

Comment: ok I added the first form to logout. I'm using Spring MVC so I really don't have any POST or GET method in my Controller.

Comment: IT has nothing to do with your controller... Spring Security is handling the logout NOT you .... I you have a controller for `/logout` you are basically breaking Spring Securities logout functionality.

Comment: ok. I don't have any /logout /login redirection in my controller.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```html
href="<c:url value="/logout"/>"
```

Comment: Yes, I tried to use <c:url value="/logout" var="logoutUrl" />
<a href="${logoutUrl}">Log Out</a>