# /j_spring_security_logout is not working in Spring security 4.0

Tags: java, spring-security

I am writing a security application with spring security 4.0. As part of that I want to make a logout call. It is simply giving 404 - Not Found.Here is my code.

**spring-security.xml**

```
 <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" logout-success-url="/login"/>
```

**Jsp**

```
<button class="logoutbtn"><a href="j_spring_security_logout">Loout</a></button>
```

Is there anything to confugure much than this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36240240/3635454

Answer (score 0):

A few URI changed between Spring security 3 and 4. [Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html) are the details about the migrations in Spring Security.

On one part of this document, you have this: [Migrating Logout](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-xmlnamespace-logout)

This should help you solve your problem