# Spring Security: 404 on logout

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

When I try to access the logout URL of my spring application, I get a 404 error and `No mapping found for HTTP Request with URI [/logout] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'` in my server log.

I have already tried [Call to j_spring_security_logout not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050840/call-to-j-spring-security-logout-not-working), [Issue with Spring security's logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068637/issue-with-spring-securitys-logout) and pretty much all of the related results on SO.

I'm including the complete configuration files as the Spring xml structure isn't quite clear to me yet.

My security configuration:

```xml
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/"/>
        <logout logout-url="/logout" />
        <csrf />
    </http>

    <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService" />
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

My `web.xml` is this:

```xml
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>XYZ</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/*-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

How do I make the logout page work?

Comment: I really can't see anything wrong. It seems spring security's filter is not picking up your logout request for some reason. I'd try setting up breakpoints there and try to see what happens in the debugger. Also, although it shouldn't matter, perhaps try changing spring security version, there was a version that had some bugs regarding logouts.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you are using logout with CSRF you must perform a POST. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-logout

Comment: Ahh, this sounds sensible. I'll try it out later.

Comment: Note that using spring's `<form:form>` tag will automatically add the `_csrf` hidden token automatically for you.

Comment: @BrettRyan but then you have to use a command object. What would you use for a case like this?

Comment: How can I do the logout when my client is AngularJS, the request will be sent from html file there.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem after migrating from Spring 3.2 to 4 but I wanted to logout using a link on the view.

The Spring doco (http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-include-csrf-token-form) explains how to do it in the view.

I used this snippet in the JSP to do the logout:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Logout" />
</form:form>
```

Comment: It worked for me using this action: `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_logout` and in the security context enabling: `<security:intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_logout" access="permitAll" />` and also `<security:logout logout-success-url="/loggedout" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"/>`

Answer (score 7):

Try this, logout with HTTP.GET

`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
// In HttpSecurity configure
...
.logout()
...
.logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", “GET”))
...
...
```

`HTML`

```
<a href="/logout">Logout</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to solve this, it's usually required to convert a logout link into a POST form button with hidden CSRF token, which can be achieved by:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();"> Logout </a>

<form id="logout-form" action="<c:url value="/logout"/>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
</form>
```